# AnyLogic rackpick with two resources

Tags: resources, anylogic

I want to implement a rack pick with two resources: one worker and one pallet trolley (actually, I have many operations with this combination). One of the workers has to go to one of the pallet trolleys and than do a rack pick or rack store. I can't figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this you need to do a lot of stuff... I can give you some guidelines to do that... because certain it depends on your situation... This is the model structure... it doesn't include putting back the trolley in its place after storing in the rack, but you can figure that out:

[image: structure of model]

1. you generate a pallet
2. you seize the worker
3. you move the worker to the area where the trolleys are and the worker waits there until a trolley is available
4. you move the worker to the trolley that is available
5. you move both worker and trolley towards the pallet
6. you attach the pallet to the resources
7. you use rackstore WITHOUT resources

Now.. this is the most basic form, but it does what you want... if you want it to look pretty, you need to have an offset in your trolley's position so your worker seems to be behind it.